# VirtualAlloc. Последовательное выделение динамической памяти

Tags: c, winapi

Приложение x86. Для следующего кода

```
void *a = VirtualAlloc(0, 0x14000000, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
void *b = VirtualAlloc(0, 0x8000000, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
void *c = VirtualAlloc(0, 0x18000000, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

"иногда" `c` равняется 0 `GetLastError() == 8` (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY), следовательно, приложение не может продолжить свою работу и завершается. Лечится перезагрузкой системы.

Если не перезагружать и поменять местами первую и третью строчки - всё будет работать нормально. Повторный обмен обязательно приводит к этой же проблеме. По каким причинам приведенный код не может работать?

Comment: Размер оперативной памяти не имеет значения, вы ведь выделяете виртуальную память.

Comment: Ну и вы выделяете по пол-гигабайта памяти, в зависимости от того, как расположились уже выделенные к этому моменту структуры, места может и не хватить. Не забывайте, юзермодовская память процесса в x86 ограничена двумя гигабайтами. Может банально не найтись свободного куска подходящей длины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь выделить три непрерывных куска памяти размером 320, 128, 384 мегабайт. Когда Вы откусываете 320 и 128, то **непрерывного** куска в 384 мегабайта уже может не оказаться. Тогда как при выделении 320 и 384 мегабайт шанс найти непрерывный кусок в 128 мегабайт значительно выше (в три раза). Если Вам реально нужны такие объемы памяти, то резервируйте все сразу одним куском. А потом нарезайте как Вам нужно

```
void *a = VirtualAlloc(0, (320 + 128 + 384) * 1024 * 1024, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
void *b = (char*)a + 320 * 1024 * 1024;
void *c = (char*)a + 128 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: И если случилось несчастье и не хватает места для большого куска?..

Comment: Может ли система придумать что-нибуть еще или просто скажет "простите, не могу"?

Comment: @T-Max не понял вопроса. Если Вам нужна память и она у системы есть - Вы ее получите. Если нет - не получите. Что еще система может придумать?